# Is there a possibility to parallelize function with pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want using pyspark to parallelize python methods for example with the map function.
Is there an possibility that each RDD are getting exactly one map function?

For example: I create two RDD's like rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2],2) and now I want map each RDD with a function like rdd.map(lambda x: func(x)).
In the function func, I need a new random number for each RDD. But that isn't working with local[2], because they using the same random number.

Is there anybody, who can help me?

Comment: use dataframe and the `pyspark.sql.functions.rand()` function

Comment: Hi @mck, thank you for your comment. Is there also an alternative. Because, I want a random number from a specific list, e.g. list = [10,20,30,40,50] which used in the function.

Comment: use pyspark.sql.functions.rand() as a random index and get the element in the list according to the random index